# What is an HTML BB button? When should it be used?

Tags: html

I'm reading up on HTML 5 and the list of tags contains a:

- `<bb>` Browser button

Why would I use this one and not a `<button>` tag?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=html5+bb+tag

Comment: So far the only info I can find on `<bb>` says that it was deprecated. Can you post a link to a canonical source?

Comment: http://www.html-5.com/changes/deprecated/bb-tag.html

Comment: Reading an old skool book here

Comment: I think the key there is "old".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML `<bb>` tag is used for specifying a user agent/(browser) command that the user can invoke.

For example, the `<bb>` tag can be used to download a website as a standalone application.

The `<bb>` tag was introduced in HTML 5, but is already [deprecated](https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/html5/bb-tag.html).

More info here: 
[link](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_bb_tag.cfm)